# URL redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with redirecting single webpages within my website.
I am trying to redirect https://job-center.hu/munkaero_kozvetites/ to https://job-center.hu/munkaero-kozvetites/ and I am using the following htaccess file to do this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=/$1 [QSA]

</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.allasajanlat.job-center.hu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://allasajanlat.job-center.hu/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.job-center.hu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://job-center.hu/$1 [L,R=301]

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Redirect 301 /munkaero_kozvetites/ https://job-center.hu/munkaero-kozvetites/

#SetEnv skip-cache
```

The result is a strange URL and I am not sure if this is OK.

Would this be considered as duplicate content by Google or this is OK as it is.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between https://job-center.hu/munkaero_kozvetites/ and https://job-center.hu/munkaero-kozvetites/ ?

Also what is your problem? The returned URL? If so, what is it?

Comment: The difference is the first link uses underscore, the second one uses a dash and the one with the dash should be the good one. The returned URL is the problem. I don't know if that's ok as it is or not.

Answer (score 0):

For your question about google, Redirect 301 is a permanently redirect, which means google will consider both sites  the same content.

Comment: Thanks matan7890 would this link be ok as an end result https://job-center.hu/munkaero-kozvetites/?q=/munkaero_kozvetites/